# "The data type is not valid for the boolean operation."

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I am trying to select a set of data for a ComboBox based on the selection of the previous ComboBox. I have been lead to believe it is the `SELECT` statement in the second method, but I cannot figure out why it isn't working. When I run the application I receive this error:

> The data type is not valid for the boolean operation. [Data type (if
>   known) = int,Data type (if known) = nvarchar ].

I have attempted using `Parameter.AddWithValue` and also setting the value as a string to no avail. Would anyone mind teaching me how to correctly resolve this? Thank you.

```
private void cboCities_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cboCities.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = \Program Files\ParkSurvey\ParkSurvey.sdf; Persist Security Info = False; Password = *");
            cn.Open();
            SqlCeCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM Parks WHERE CityId ='" + cboCities.SelectedValue + "'ORDER BY Name ASC";
            SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            cn.Close();
            cboParks.ValueMember = "ParkId";
            cboParks.DisplayMember = "Name";
            cboParks.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            cboParks.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
```

Comment: can you put some more details in please - the structure of the table and what the data looks like, and whats in the cboCities.selectedValue - (type and data)

Comment: yeah.. i agree with Preet.. prehaps there's something *else* we don't know about

Comment: I won't be back around the computer with the database until Monday, but if memory serves correct, it's setup similar to this:

Cities
- CityId, int(PK) (1, 2, 3, etc)
- Name, varchar (Dallas, Fort Worth, etc)
- rowguid, uniqueidentifier.

Parks
- ParkId, int(PK) (1, 2, 3, etc)
- CityId, int(FK) ('')
- Name, varchar (Willow Creek, Tarrant, etc)
- rowguid, uniqueidentifier. 
cboCities.SelectedValue is the cboCities.ValueMember of the initial method, and is equal to CityId. I'll provide more details on Monday. Apologies for not having this information at the ready.

Answer (score 0):

Is the CityId  in the Parks table is an integer?

You are comparing an int ie CityId to a string '...value in cboCities.SelectedValue ...'

Try casting the City it to and integer :

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM Parks WHERE CAST(CityId AS NVARCAR)  ='" + cboCities.SelectedValue + "'ORDER BY Name ASC";
```

Or if you are sure that the in cboCities.SelectedValue  is the same as CityId you can also try it without the quotes (an integer to integer comparison)

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM Parks WHERE CityId = " + cboCities.SelectedValue + " ORDER BY Name ASC";
```

(note I've removed the single quotes around cboCities.SelectedValue)

Comment: it's nothing, but the 2nd one is gonna fail. Add a space before `ORDER BY`

Comment: Both of these return the following error:

There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 49, Token in error = Data ]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like the following?

```
//[...code...]    
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM Parks WHERE CityId = @CityId ORDER BY Name ASC";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CityId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 2).Value = Convert.ToInt32(cboCities.SelectedValue);
//[...code...]
```

Comment: Using this method returns an InvalidCastException.

Comment: maybe the size.. i'll check it later if you still haven't found the answer.. but try out with a size greater than 2

Comment: I changed it to the database length and the exception is still present.